What does "snakeballs" mean?
At the start of Transformers: Age of Extinction (about 6:45), Cade Yeager discovers an old truck inside an abandoned cinema. He asks the owner how much it costs:

Hey, snakeballs. How much for the truck?


(I believe the usage of this screenshot is covered by fair use.)
What does "snakeballs" mean? Google results lead to mating balls but that seems irrelevant.

It's not a real word. The literal meaning would be "testicles of a snake", but I'm pretty sure that's not what's intended.  I haven't seen the film, but I'm guessing that it's a mistake in the subtitles, the name of a character, or a made-up term of abuse. It's fairly common to just make up words of this kind by putting together two normal words, for example dickhead.

It says 'snakeballs' in two transcripts that I found using Google. I think it is probably derived from a slang expression 'lower than a snake's balls',  (very low, since snakes have no legs and move along the ground on their undersides; their testicles are in fact internal, and do not dangle externally like human mens' 'balls'.). Used jocularly as a friendly address, perhaps.

Garter snakes when mating clump together to form balls sometimes called "snakeballs", but that doesn't seem to be relevant. I'm sure there are other forms of address between men that reference testicles, e.g. "hey big balls" crops up a fair bit online.

@StuartF -I have UK heard people say 'Billy Big Bollocks' about a cocky or annoyingly self-assured male. (i.e. a 'prick'). It's usually not meant kindly. Also 'he thinks he's the dog's bollocks'.

Is the owner of the old truck an old man? If so, it could be a way of saying "old fella" but it isn't "friendly".  It's more of a gibe.  Sort of like, If your balls were any lower you'd be stepping on them.

https://www.etsy.com/listing/243675787/fake-old-man-bad-grandpa-balls-stag-do

@TimR He's middle-aged, but doesn't seem too old. Besides, there's also his grandfather, the cinema's runner for many years before he transfers the ownership to the grandchild who says "I am one diaper change away from poisoning his oatmeal" behind his back. The one being asked in this scene, however, is the grandchild.
